# Regex stopped matching after the first match

Tags: regex

I need some help here

Here is example of what im trying to match:

```
1 ScreenMail Enable friendly none Internal any 5
```

I need to match everything excluding the last digits (5) Meaning matching the first digit(1), spaces, letter, special characters, etc I tried using `/^(\d)`, but after matching the first digits, it stopped. Your assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `\d` only matches one character (a digit). You need to add more to your regex. Hint: search for `\w` and `\s` and Quantifiers `+`.

Comment: Why do you expect `\d` to match letters, spaces, etc.?

Comment: Try `.*\D`.  That matches zero or more characters followed by a character that is not a digit. Since `.*` is greedy, the non-digit matching `\D` cannot be followed later in the string by another non-digit. It therefore can only be followed by zero or more digits at the end of the string. Those trailing digits (if any) are not matched.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to remove last digits with:

```js
\d+$
\d+\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eFd5l9/1).

You may want to use a matching regex like

```js
^.*[^\d\s]
```

that matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars (`.*`) as many as possible and then a char other than a digit and whitespace. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eFd5l9/2).

However, if the digits are followed with an optional whitespace, or if you allow any text after the last digits, it will fail. You can then use

```js
^.*[^\d\s](?=\s*\d)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eFd5l9/3). The `(?=\s*\d)` positive lookahead requires zero or more whitespaces and then a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks, @wiktor-stribiżew for the help. I really appreciate you giving me multiple solutions.